# Staying secure when passing json to view model

Tags: php, json, security, codeigniter, knockout.js

I decided to use knockout.js for my web application and have some concerns regarding security.

The flow of data is as follows:

- user requests controller via url
- controller gathers together required information, sends to view as json string
- json string is saved to dom to allow my javascript code to access it
- json is loaded into knockout view model inside the $(document).ready

My issue is that the json string is clearly viewable by users by just clicking 'View Source'
 and this worries me because I'm aware this can easily be changed client-side but I'm not 
 fully sure of the implications.

Here is some example code to illustrate my point.  First, the controller:

```
 function view($id = null)
 {
    //other processing...

    $data = array();
    $data['json'] = $this->get_profile_json($id);
    $this->load->view('profile_page',$data);
 }
```

The profile page view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.profile_json = "<?php echo $json; ?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/profile_page.js'); ?>"></script>
<!-- The profile page below... -->
```

The profile page javascript

```
var vm = new ViewModel(profile_json); //load the json into view model
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Now I understand I can achieve the same goal by loading the json from the javascript code just before
creating the view model, using `$.getJSON` for example.

However, someone with a developer tools extension on their browser could also see (and possibly edit?)
this data too.  This is a particular problem is some of that data contains things like permissions flags
and so on.

My question is, how do you ensure data passed down to your view model is unable to be tampered with?

Comment: You can never avoid this problem.

Comment: That's what I thought, I was hoping I was wrong though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to ever guarantee the safety of your information from the client side.  This is why it is always important to do server side checks on the information, and then send back your response on whether the information is usable or not.

For some security checks you should use the following:

```
1) Strip_tags($_POST['key'])
2) Check to see if the value is numeric (if its a number)
3) Check to see if it only has alphabet and numbers (if this is all that's allowed)
...and so on
```

The client side information to be passed to your back-end can always be tampered with, which is why it is important to lock it down as much as possible and if any information does not appear to be valid then you should immediately throw an error to the client and ask them to try again :)

Assuming the back-end data is safe, then the front-end data should never have a problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure this helps me in the situation where I pass down some flags in my json like `LoggedIn: true` to the view model.  In this case, the view model will enable certain elements in the UI if logged in.  If someone could just change that value then it will break the UI...

Comment: Of course, I always double check on the server side for things like a user being logged in so the only issue would be a hacker getting a broken UI... probably not worth worrying about!

Comment: Exactly, as long as they can't damage the back-end by passing invalid data, then you don't care what they do to their client side (the UI) they could make it rainbows and pokadots and only they can see it, so who cares :)

Comment: The problem you mention @peacemaker is why you frequently see long, gibberish looking strings in uris, query strings and variables; come up with a pseud-random identifier for every logged in session to identify itself to the server, use https for all communication, and you don't have to worry about someone being able to enable portions of their ui; the server is still secure from their bogus queries.